# How to define a spring bean in a context and implement it in another context in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to define a bean in a parent context as an interface, then create another context that imports the parent context and provides an implementation for that bean.

I successfully did this with plain spring:

```
public interface SecurityProvider {
  Credentials getCredentials(String user);
}

@Configuration
public abstract class ParentConfig {
  @Bean public abstract SecurityProvider securityProvider();
}

@Configuration
@Import(ParentConfig.class)
public class ChildConfig {
  @Bean public SecurityProvider securityProvider() { 
    return new SecurityProviderImpl();
  }
}
```

I haven't seen this documented anywhere, but it works: I wrote a test that uses the SpringExtension, declares ChildConfig inside `@ContextConfiguration` and autowires the securityProvider, which is an instance of SecurityProviderImpl. If the ChildContext doesn't declare exactly the same method signature for the securityProvider bean, I get an AbstractMethodError, which makes sense. Note also that the ChildContext does not extend the ParentContext, but imports it with `@Import`.

However, when I use the ChildContext in a spring-boot application, I get an error claiming that the securityProvider bean is defined twice (in ParentConfig and ChildConfig). If I remove the securityProvider definition in the child context, I get an AbstractMethodError.

Has anybody seen this feature documented in spring, and how can I make it work in spring-boot?

Thanks